# PDO best way to check if 300+ values exist in database

Tags: php, mysql, caching, optimization, pdo

I have a time dependent script I am working on and used microtime() to find the bottle neck.  I determined the time increase is caused by doing a check on 300+ values to see if they exist in a database one at a time at 0.04 seconds a query.

The background of the script is it is a caching script.  I need to see if it exists in the DB so I need a true/false (obtained by a rowCount) but i also need a way to relate a false to a value so I can update it. I know using a WHERE tag IN (:ARRAY) would work faster than the individual calls, but I cant think of a way to apply an association of true/false to value in this method.

My current code is below:

```
//loop through all our values!
    //prepare out reusuable statement
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * from cache WHERE value=?");

foreach($values as $tempVal)
{
    //find if its in the database
    try
    {
        $stmt->execute(array($tempVal));
        $valCount = $stmt->rowCount();
    } catch(PDOException $ex) {
        echo "PDO error send this to us: " . $ex->getMessage();
    }

    //update flag
    $addToUpdate = 1;

    //if its in the database
    if($valCount > 0)
    {
        //get the tag data
        $valRes= $stmt->fetch();

        //check if cache expired
                    $addToUpdate = 0;
    } 

    //add to update list
    if($addToUpdate)
    {
                    //needs updating
        $updateList[] = $tempVal;

        //add to not in DB list to minimize queries
        if($tagTCount == 0)
        {
            $notInDB[$tempVal] = $tempVal;
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions? I can explain more if anything is not clear.

Thank you,
Nick

Comment: You're better off using `value IN (?,?,?,?,?,?,...)` in place of the loop. Use a PDO wrapper library which generates the SQL query from your array/list. You do get the association from `SELECT *` which should contain the individual `value` values. Map the returned list onto your PHP source array.

Comment: @mario so you are saying that each fetch() would return either the select or "null" depending on in the tag related to that existed (presumably in order it was put into the IN array)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you just issue your query with the complete array, using the `IN (?,?,?,?,?...)` list:

```
// abstract, use a PDO wrapper of your choosing
$query = db("SELECT * FROM cache WHERE value IN (??)", $values);
```

Then iterate over the result list. Only matched $values will return. So build your first list from that:

```
foreach ($query as $row) {
     $updateList[] = $row["value"];
}
```

To get the list of absent entries, just [diff](http://php.net/array_diff) that against your original array:

```
$notInDB = array_diff($values, $updateList);
```

You could of course use a second `NOT IN` query. But doing that differentiation in PHP is simpler.

Comment: literally cut down from 14 seconds to 1. Thank you for helping me through that one, i was expecting to get NULL for non-found values.